# How to create an empty group in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I know that ng-grid uses aggregation to group rows[1], so it's not officially supported.

Is there a nice workaround to create a header of aggregation without a row? Or way to use an empty row and don't display it?

I need to aggregate users by group, but I have to list all groups without users too.

Something like:

Group 1 (users : 5)
-User 1
-User 2
-User 3
-User 4
-User 5
Group 2 (users: 0)
Group 3 (users: 1)
- User 6

[1] [How to set aggregation with grouping in ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015088/how-to-set-aggregation-with-grouping-in-ng-grid)