# need unique Angularjs table which is simple to compile in controller and need to support grouping

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can any one suggest me the best Angularjs table to meet the following requirements :
1. It should be very simple to compile in the controller like

```
var template =  ' <div class="table-container"> <smart-table  config="globalConfig" columns="columnCollection" rows="rowCollection"></smart-table>   </div> '

    angular.element(document.querySelector('.body')).append($compile(template)($scope));
```

2. It should support column grouping and sum of individual groups and total column sum.
3. Table titles have to be set dynamically using model values (https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/468)

Initially I used smart table even though it is easy to compile in controller, it is not supporting the grouping. So I shifted to ngTable. In ngTable even though it is supporting columns grouping, compiling the template in controller is not so simple as that of smart table and it is difficult to set titles dynamically based on model values (https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/468). So now I am looking for single Angular js table which full fills all these criteria.

Now I am planning to shift to ngGrid/UI grid, even though the template compilation becomes easier here, but I am seeing in forums that grouping is problem in this. Can any one suggest any Angularjs Table to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping works fine with ngGrid. I would highly recommend it. However, grouping is not yet implemented for uiGrid (which is the next iteration of ngGrid & currently in alpha).

Comment: Is there any sample code to get grouping sums using ng grid? On the official website I see only simple Grouping example. What about dynamically setting titles based on model values? Is it possible in ng Grid.

Comment: For subtotals, I know for sure you can add subtotals for each column. However, I've never tried adding subtotals based on grouping. This might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015088/how-to-set-aggregation-with-grouping-in-ng-grid. For titles (aka Column Headers), you can dynamically change them whenever you want. You can either change a specific column header or iterate through all of them using something like this: `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[i].displayName = newColumnHeader`.

Comment: please find my plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/ZyS8FgzvXsSwAkNiaOdq?p=preview. Here I want all month columns to be deleted (month5, month6, month7, ... etc) and columns titles for spends have to be replaced with its months, i.e., instead column title spend5, I need to have 6-14, in place of spend5, similarly the title spend6 should be 7-14, spend7 should be 8-14, etc is it possible to achieve this?