# How to pass a function to angular ui-grid column total

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular ui-grid (no ng-grid) and want to pass a function to calculate a column's total value. In the documentation they explicitly say it is possible; it is just that I can´t find how to do it.

This is how I'm showing a total (sum) for another columns:

```
aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
aggregationHideLabel: true,
footerCellFilter: 'currencyFilter', 
footerCellClass: 'ui-grid-centerCell'
```

Now, instead of using *uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum*, I want to pass a function to calculate the value.

Many thanks and bye ...

Answer (score 0):

My Idea is to Create a method in your Controller like

```
$scope.sum = function(row){
var sum1 = row.entity.sum1 + row.entity.sum2;
console.log('Sum of Value is = ',sum1);
}
```

Note : sum1 and sum2 is columnDefs of Field value like

```
$scope.gridsOptions = {
columnDefs : [
        {
            field : 'sum1',
            name :'xx'
        },
        {
            field : 'sum2',
            name : 'xxx'
        }
 ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by adding custom tree aggregation.

```
 treeCustomAggregations: {
  sum: { 
   aggregationFn: stats.aggregator.sumSquareErr, finalizerFn: function (aggregation) { 
   //Do rest of your calculations here
   var total = $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[column_number].getAggregationValue() ;
  aggregation.value = total ;
  aggregation.rendered = (aggregation.value).toFixed(1);
 }
```

Or you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015088/how-to-set-aggregation-with-grouping-in-ng-grid) question for custom aggregate template and calling your custom function from it.